# UI Update not triggered on Main Thread despite @MainActor annotation

Tags: swift, macos, actor, appkit, swift-concurrency

I am annotating my function with `@MainActor` to ensure that it can be called from any async location safely to trigger a UI Update. Despite, I run into an error where, somehow, the UI Update seems to be attempted on a background thread, even though (to my understanding) the function is strictly bound to the `@MainActor´.

This is my code:

```swift
/// Dismisses the popup from its presenting view controller.
@MainActor public func dismiss() {
    presentingViewController?.dismiss(self)
}
```

It is called from inside an `NSViewController` which listens to a certain event using `NotificationCenter`, after which it initiates dismissal in the following `objc` func:

```swift
class MainWindowControllerVC: NSWindowController, NSWindowDelegate {
  override func windowDidLoad() {
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.dismissVCastSharePopup), name: .NOTIF_DISMISS_POPUP, object: nil)
  }

  @objc private func dismissPopup() {
      // some other cleanup is happening here
      popup?.dismiss()
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

```bash
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!'
```

and the following warnings:

[image]

Can somebody please explain how this is possible? What am I misunderstanding here? If I wrap the same code into a `DispatchQueue.main.async` or even `Task { @MainActor () -> Void in ... }` I don't get this error. It is specifically tied to the annotation before the function.

Comment: What does the call site look like?

Comment: @jnpdx the call site is an asynchronous function that can execute on the Main Thread or on another, background thread

Comment: You should show the call site. If you’re using it in a place that doesn’t have the guarantees of Swift concurrency, it could lead to unexpected results. Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @jnpdx I just changed my question to include the call site that calls the function. does this help?

Comment: The `@objc` is a good sign that you are not in a place with guarantees of Swift concurrency. You may want to check out the concurrency videos from WWDC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

tl;dr

When you isolate a function to the `@MainActor`, that is only relevant when you call this method from a Swift concurrency context. If you call it from outside the Swift concurrency system (such as from the `NotificationCenter`), the `@MainActor` qualifier has no effect.

So, either call this actor isolated function from Swift concurrency context, or rely on legacy `main` queue patterns.

---

There are a variety of ways to fix this. First, let me refactor your example into a MCVE:

```swift
import Cocoa
import os.log

private let logger = Logger(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "ViewController")

extension Notification.Name {
    static let demo = Notification.Name(rawValue: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".demo")
}

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .demo, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addObserver()
        postFromBackground()
    }

    func addObserver() {
        logger.debug(#function)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(notificationHandler(_:)), name: .demo, object: nil)
    }

    func postFromBackground() {
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            logger.debug(#function)
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .demo, object: nil)
        }
    }

    @objc func notificationHandler(_ notification: Notification) {
        checkQueue()
    }

    @MainActor func checkQueue() {
        logger.debug(#function)
        dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))
        logger.debug("OK")
    }
}
```

[image]

There are a few ways of solving this:

1. My `notificationHandler` (`dismissVCastSharePopup` in your example) is not within a Swift concurrency context. But I can bridge into Swift concurrency by wrapping the the call in a `Task {…}`:

   ```swift
   @objc nonisolated func notificationHandler(_ notification: Notification) {
       Task { await checkQueue() }
   }
   ```

   Note, not only did I wrap the call in a `Task {…}`, but I also added a `nonisolated` qualifier to let the compiler know that this was being called from a nonisolated context. (Methinks it should infer that from the `@objc` qualifier, but it does not currently.)
2. Alternatively, you can fall back to legacy patterns to make sure you're on the main thread, such as the block-based `addObserver` which allows you to specify the `.main` queue:

   ```swift
   private var observerToken: NSObjectProtocol?

   func addObserver() {
       observerToken = notificationCenter.addObserver(forName: .demo, object: nil, queue: .main) { [weak self] _ in
           self?.checkQueue()
       }

       …
   }
   ```

   Perhaps needless to say, even though we are no longer using the `@objc` selector method in this latter example, this closure will not be called in an actor isolated context, either, and therefore it will ignore the `@MainActor` attribute. The above pattern works solely because I followed legacy patterns and explicitly specified the `.main` queue to handle this observer.